# MEAN stack issue with posting form data

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Evening All,

I'm trying to build a simple register page with mongodb, node, express, mongoose and angularJS.

I'm struggling to understand the relationship between all of the components and how to wire them all together.

This is my form...

```
<div class="main">
    <p class="sign" align="center">Register</p>
    <form class="form1">
        <input class="un " type="email" align="center" placeholder="Email" name="username" required>
        <input class="pass" type="password" align="center" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" align="center" ng-click="submit()">Register</button>
</div>
```

My controller for that view...

```
angular.module('registerCtrl', [])

.controller('registerController', function ($scope, $http, dataService) {

    $scope.submit= function(){
        console.log('clicked submit');
        $http.post('/RegisterUser').then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status)
        })
    }
});
```

server.js for server and db logic...

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
});

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))
app.use(express.static('node_modules'));
app.use(express.static('public'));


const port = 3000;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server is running on port 3000');

//POSTS

app.post("/RegisterUser", function (req, res) {
    const newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    newUser.save();


})
```

view routes...

```
angular.module('app.routes', [])

  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "views/Login.html"
      })
      .when("/Register", {
        templateUrl: "views/Register.html",
        controller: "registerController"
      })
      .when("/Home", {
        templateUrl: "views/Home.html",
        controller: "homeController"
      })
      .when("/CocktailDetails", {
        templateUrl: "views/CocktailDetails.html",
        controller: "cocktailDetailsController"
      })
      .when("/Favourites", {
        templateUrl: "views/Favourites.html",
        controller: "favouritesController"
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
      })

  })
```

Essentially what I want to achieve is simply posting the inputted email and password to the database and then, if the POST was successful divert the view route to my home view.

Should I be passing in the data from the form into the post request in my controller as opposed to the server side? As currently the post data is being passed as null.

Is someone able to explain the best way to achieve this and describe the relationship between the database, server and client side framework in this scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Client

It looks like your form is missing `ng-models` and you're also not posting their data.  Add `ng-model` to the inputs:

```html
<input type="email" ng-model="form.username">
<input type="password" ng-model="form.password">
```

Also create their bindings in the controller.  Then pass the form data along to the server when you post:

```js
.controller('registerController', function ($scope, $http, $location, dataService) {
    // injecting $location now ^
    $scope.form = {  // <-- An object whose properties are bound to the form inputs
      username: '',
      password: ''
    }
    $scope.submit = function(){
        console.log('clicked submit');
        $http.post('/RegisterUser', $scope.form) // <-- posting `$scope.form` data now
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
            $location.path('/Home'); // <-- redirecting to Home route
        })
    }
});
```

## Server

Since there was no data being posted before, `req.body` was empty on the server.  The server is also not sending back a response.  If you wanted to send back the user object, you could add this to the server route after `newUser.save()`:

```js
return res.status(200).send(newUser);
```

`send` is what sends a response, `return` just exits the function.

Comment: Thanks Dan. The issue now is whilst the post request sends the correct form data, the post request just stays pending and doesn't resolve. I can see an object is created in the DB but it's just a blank document.

Comment: You're welcome.  I added a redirect to the home route, and explained how to send a server response with some data.  You could put some logic in the server to send back a different response based on success/failure, but this should get you started.